Installing Device Admin & Device Owner App
I'm writing a device owner application, where I'm setting the app as device owner via ADB command:
adb shell dpm set-device-owner {package-name}/{admin-receiver}

The app is successfully set as a Device Owner.
But when I make changes to the app and run it again (via Android Studio) I get timed out while terminating the app.
So, when I try to run the command
adb shell dpm remove-active-admin com.latticen/com.latticen.admin.LatticenAdminReceiver

I get the following error:
Exception occurred while executing 'remove-active-admin':
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown URI content://telephony/carriers/enforce_managed
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:2396)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:2362)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.lambda$setOverrideApnsEnabledUnchecked$130$com-android-server-devicepolicy-DevicePolicyManagerService(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:16472)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda14.getOrThrow(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.os.Binder.withCleanCallingIdentity(Binder.java:449)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService$Injector.binderWithCleanCallingIdentity(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:1585)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setOverrideApnsEnabledUnchecked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:16472)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.clearOverrideApnUnchecked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:8763)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.clearDeviceOwnerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:8804)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.lambda$forceRemoveActiveAdmin$10$com-android-server-devicepolicy-DevicePolicyManagerService(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3599)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService$$ExternalSyntheticLambda130.runOrThrow(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Binder.withCleanCallingIdentity(Binder.java:425)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService$Injector.binderWithCleanCallingIdentity(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:1581)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.forceRemoveActiveAdmin(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:3589)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.runRemoveActiveAdmin(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:280)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.onCommand(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:93)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.onShellCommand(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9900)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1049)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:877)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:6054)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)

Last week I was able to remove the device owner by running the same command. But now, each time I try to remove the device owner I get the same error. Even when I call DevicePolicyManager.clearDeviceOwner, I get the same error in logcat.
I've tried setting android:testOnly in the manifest too.

If you set your app as a device admin using set-active-admin then you can remove it with remove-active-admin.
But if you set your app as device owner with set-device-owner without specifying android:testOnly="true" in the manifest file then you can not remove like that.
Now you have to factory reset the device in order to re-install it, this time make sure to add testOnly flag in the manifest file.

I know about the android:testOnly flag. As I mentioned in the question. Android Studio is supposed to add it for debug builds on its own. However, I still added the flag in hopes that maybe there was a bug in AS.

The documentation says the same, "Android Studio automatically adds this attribute when you click Run".
